# degree of multivariate polynomial in a quotient ring.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm trying to work with polynomials on Elliptic curves. Thus polynomials are elements of the ring \begin{equation*}
\frac{K[X,Y]}{Y^2-X^3-aX-b}
\end{equation*}
(Field characteristic is supposed to be different from 2 or 3)

How can I define the degree of a polynomial in this ring? 
My problem is that if I put x and y to be degree 1 the relation $Y^2=X^3-aX-b$ does not hold anymore in terms of the degree.
Does anyone have an idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Elements in that ring should NOT be viewed as polynomials, so there is no reason why you should have a reasonable definition of degree.

Comment: what about the minimal representants of the equivalence classes?

Comment: which properties do you expect from a definition of degree?

Comment: @Ferra  Any reason to consider that elements as not polynomials? Informally, one would replace all $Y^2$'s with $X^3 + aX + b$ resulting in bivariate polynomials, that could be considered as linear in $Y$ (of degree at most one) with coefficients that are polynomials in $X$.